# loop with two different indexes at the same time in R

Tags: r

```
b<-matrix(0,23,1)
for(i in 69:91)
{       
  b[i,1]<-((as.numeric(daaata$t[i])-58.16410)^2)
}
```

I want to go through two different indexes in one loop, since b is a 0 to 23 matrix and the number I want to use in Calculation is `daaata$t[69]` to `daaata$t[91]`.

how do I have a loop with two different indexes, I also try the inner loop, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `daaata` like?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Here, we could use the sequence of the index instead of the actual index.  As the number of rows of 'b' is the same as the `length` from 69 to 91, use the sequence

```
ind1 <- 69:91
for(i in seq_len(nrow(b)) {
      b[i, 1] <- ((as.numeric(daaata$t[ind1[i]])-58.16410)^2)
  }
```

---

A `for` loop is not really needed as these operations are `vectorized`

```
b[, 1] <- ((as.numeric(daaata$t[ind1]) - 58.16410) ^2)
```